# Table cell is not displaying the value I expect in Razor MVC 4

Tags: html, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a table in my view, and the first two cells in the table show the value I expect in the second cell.  In other words, I'm not seeing the value I expect in the first cell of the table.  It's picking up the value of the second cell, and I can't figure out why.  I see the value I expect in the HTML source of the page, so I'm stumped as to why the page itself doesn't show the right value in the first cell.

I expect the first column (Vendor*) to show 65126, and the second cell (Vendor #) to show 001070.

Here's the table:

```
                <table class="grid">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col />
                        <col />
                        <col />
                        <col />
                        <col />
                        <col />
                        <col />
                        <col />
                        <col />
                    </colgroup>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Vendor*</th>
                            <th>Vendor #</th>
                            <th>Item #</th>
                            <th>Case Pack*</th>
                            <th>Case Cost*</th>
                            <th>Cost Start Date*</th>
                            <th>OI Allowance</th>
                            <th>OI Start Date</th>
                            <th>OI End Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="vendorItems">
                        @{int i = 0;}
                        @foreach (var vendorItem in this.Model.GetVendorItems())
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @vendorItem.VendorId
                                    <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[@i].VendorId" value="@vendorItem.VendorId" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @(vendorItem.VendorId != null ? this.Model.GetVendorNumber(vendorItem.VendorId) : "")
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @vendorItem.VendorItemNumber
                                    <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[@i].VendorItemNumber" value="@vendorItem.VendorItemNumber" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @vendorItem.CasePack
                                    <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[@i].CasePack" value="@vendorItem.CasePack" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @vendorItem.CaseCost
                                    <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[@i].CaseCost" value="@vendorItem.CaseCost" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @(vendorItem.CostStartDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)vendorItem.CostStartDate).ToShortDateString() : "")
                                    <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[@i].CostStartDate" value="@vendorItem.CostStartDate" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @vendorItem.Allowance
                                    <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[@i].Allowance" value="@vendorItem.Allowance" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @(vendorItem.AllowanceStartDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)vendorItem.AllowanceStartDate).ToShortDateString() : "")
                                    <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[@i].AllowanceStartDate" value="@vendorItem.AllowanceStartDate" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @(vendorItem.AllowanceEndDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)vendorItem.AllowanceEndDate).ToShortDateString() : "")
                                    <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[@i].AllowanceEndDate" value="@vendorItem.AllowanceEndDate" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            i++;
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Which renders the following HTML:

```
<table class="grid">
                            <colgroup>
                                <col />

                                <col />
                                <col />
                                <col />
                                <col />
                                <col />
                                <col />
                                <col />
                                <col />
                            </colgroup>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Vendor*</th>
                                    <th>Vendor #</th>
                                    <th>Item #</th>
                                    <th>Case Pack*</th>
                                    <th>Case Cost*</th>
                                    <th>Cost Start Date*</th>
                                    <th>OI Allowance</th>
                                    <th>OI Start Date</th>
                                    <th>OI End Date</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="vendorItems">

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            65126
                                            <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[0].VendorId" value="65126" />
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            001070
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                            <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[0].VendorItemNumber" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            1
                                            <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[0].CasePack" value="1" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            1.0000
                                            <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[0].CaseCost" value="1.0000" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            4/23/2014
                                            <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[0].CostStartDate" value="4/23/2014 12:00:00 AM" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                            <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[0].Allowance" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                            <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[0].AllowanceStartDate" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                            <input type="hidden" name="TempVendorItems[0].AllowanceEndDate" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

But this is what the page shows:
[image: table]

Comment: I copied and pasted your rendered HTML into a new web page and brought it up in a browser. It shows the value 65126 under the Vendor heading. Do you have any JavaScript or CSS that might be mucking things up for you? Once the HTML hits the browser it has nothing to do with EF, MVC, or Razor.

Comment: something is happening with kendo.  Hmmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the column heading!  I guess kendo could not distinguish between the column names of the first two columns.  I changed "Vendor #" to "Vendor Num" and it fixed the problem.

I changed:

```
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Vendor*</th>
                            <th>Vendor #</th>
                            <th>Item #</th>
                            <th>Case Pack*</th>
                            <th>Case Cost*</th>
                            <th>Cost Start Date*</th>
                            <th>OI Allowance</th>
                            <th>OI Start Date</th>
                            <th>OI End Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
```

To:

```
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Vendor*</th>
                            <th>Vendor Num</th>
                            <th>Item #</th>
                            <th>Case Pack*</th>
                            <th>Case Cost*</th>
                            <th>Cost Start Date*</th>
                            <th>OI Allowance</th>
                            <th>OI Start Date</th>
                            <th>OI End Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
```